# Is it possitlbe to Word wrap a textfield

Tags: extjs4.1, textfield, word-wrap

[image]

The textfield value is 'This is a long text. Can this go to second line?'.

Is it possible to word wrap a textfield. Basically if the text is too long, is there a way to wrap it to second line.

I know I could use a textarea, but it takes too much space(height) if the value is short. And I can't find a way to wrap a value on textfield if it's too long (long enough only to go second line).

thanks

Comment: You can't. But you can make a tiny textarea.

Comment: Thanks dbrin... but I can't find anything about tiny on sencha docs. Could you please elaborate on that? Thanks

Comment: have you tried rows: 2 and grow:true ?

Comment: Yes I tried that dbrin. But the problem with rows: 2 is that when the text is short, there is that extra space below row 1. I tried doing row: 1 but it doesn't expand when the text is long.

Comment: you tried setting grow property ?

Comment: yes dbrin, using grow: true actually makes it worse. It ignores rows: 1 property and shows default size.